# how to show only the dates that correspond to the top 4 highest values in a line chart in r

Tags: r, ggplot2, linechart

I have this df and i have created a line plot . I am trying to plot only the dates with the 4 highest values.

```
dput(df)
structure(list(Date = c("2021-06-22", "2021-06-23", "2021-06-24", 
"2021-06-25", "2021-06-26", "2021-06-27", "2021-06-28", "2021-06-29", 
"2021-06-30", "2021-07-01", "2021-07-02", "2021-07-03", "2021-07-04", 
"2021-07-05", "2021-07-06", "2021-07-07", "2021-07-08", "2021-07-09", 
"2021-07-10", "2021-07-11", "2021-07-12", "2021-07-13", "2021-07-14", 
"2021-07-15", "2021-07-16", "2021-07-17", "2021-07-18", "2021-07-19", 
"2021-07-20", "2021-07-21"), Volume = c(30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 
30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 
27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 31L, 30L), 
    Percentage = c(6.67, 3.33, 10, 10, 3.33, 3.33, 6.67, 10, 
    3.33, 6.67, 10, 13.33, 13.33, 10, 6.67, 6.67, 10, 10, 3.7, 
    3.7, 3.7, 3.7, 11.11, 7.41, 11.11, 10, 13.33, 13.33, 12.9, 
    10)), row.names = c(NA, -30L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

this is the line chart

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = Date, y = Percentage,group=1)) +       
  geom_line() + geom_point()
```

Comment: If there are ties for highest values,

Comment: There are some duplicate elements, I am not sure what you really wanted.  May be `df %>% group_by(Volume) %>% slice_max(n = 4, order_by = Percentage) %>% ungroup %>% mutate(Date = as.Date(Date)) %>% ggplot(aes(x = Date, y = Percentage,group=1)) +       
   geom_line() + geom_point()`

Comment: in my line chart there are a few dots that are at the highest point of the graph and so indicate a higher percentage. I would like to emphasise the dates that have the 4  highest percentage by showing only those 4 dates on the x-axis and no other date. Basically, I want to keep my line charts exactly as it is and at the x-axis show only the 4 dates that correspond on the 4 highest percentages @akrun

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `percentage` values have ties in them so I have selected 4 random values but conceptually you can do this using `scale_x_continuous` specifying `labels` and `breaks` for the dates that you want to display.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

data <- summary_final_by_date %>%
  mutate(label = as.Date(ifelse(dense_rank(-Percentage) %in% 1:4, Date, '')), 
         Date  = as.Date(Date))

unique_dates <- unique(na.omit(data$label))[c(1, 4, 10, 16)]

ggplot(data, aes(x = as.numeric(Date), y = Percentage)) +       
  geom_line() + geom_point() + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = as.numeric(unique_dates), 
                     labels = format(unique_dates, format = "%d %b")) + 
  xlab('Date')
```

[image]